# How to compile JAVA on Sublime text 2 using Mac OS X?

Tags: java, compilation

I've looked all over the internet only finding very complicated results and now im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sublime text 2 has builtin Java support:

[image]

Which means that once you have opened the Java source, all you have to do is press <kbd>command+B</kbd>

---

What you described in the comments is a bit different - you should update your post with this information!

Devin posted a gist solution [here](https://gist.github.com/DevinClark/1633819):

You should add a new build-system by going to the menu:

Tools --> Build System --> New Build System

and add the following json and save it as "Java.sublime-build" into the default directory (which is something like: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/`):

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name"],
    "cmd": ["java", "$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Next time you want to *compile & run* use "Java.sublime-build" from your build-systems.

Comment: javac: invalid flag: 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
[Finished in 2.7s with exit code 2]
[shell_cmd: javac ""]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: thats what comes up when i build