# How to compile a java project with a terminal/cmd

Tags: java

I got tired of using Eclipse because it was too "plain" and "old style". So I moved on to a program called Sublime Text 3 and I used a package named "material theme" which made the program look flat and all nice and stuff.

But I wanted to code Java in that but I don't know how to compile stuff without using an IDE and it was not easy to find out but I found out that you could do it through the terminal/cmd of your operating system.

But what I don't understand is how I could actually use the `javac` command which means Java Compile and I searched and I didn't find out because I couldn't understand anything that was posted on either YouTube or Stack Overflow because I'm new to this whole terminal/cmd Java Compiling thing.

Comment: Where did you lookup? My first google search returned a [decent tutorial](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/).

Comment: i searched on Google, YouTube & Stack overflow

Comment: also it says the command is unrecognized that's also a problem

Comment: I mentioned about Google in my comment.

Comment: A build infrastructure like **maven** providing versioned library dependencies and conventions on directories.

Comment: So, Eclipse was "Old Style", so you decided to use technology that was mostly popular up to the '90s? And none of the loads of themes that can be downloaded from the Eclipse marketplace was "new" enough for your taste? Anyway, did you try [Oracle's Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html)?

Comment: +1 for tackling the command line thing. It is a shame that a great percentage of programmers don't have the slightest idea how to compile code without an IDE.

Comment: damn realskeptic calm down like sh*t relax you know i only moved to that because 1 eclipse slows down your coding 2 eclipse is really simple and i want to have more possibilities 3 im not lazy like you

Comment: What "more possibilities" do you have from using Sublime Text instead of Eclipse? In my experience using an IDE *speeds up* coding by exhibiting a greater understanding of the language, enabling refactoring, simple navigation etc. While it's definitely a good idea to know how to compile from the command-line, I think you're dismissing Eclipse way too soon...

Comment: everybody has there own opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're almost there buddy!

Just be sure you have the `Java Development Kit (JDK)` installed in your system. The JDK provides you the command `javac` -which you need to compile your `.java` program files.

The `javac` command is not that friendly as you think it is. You have to let it know where to find the java file you want to compile.

For example you saved `Main.java` inside `C:\Projects\Java` you must compile it this way `javac C:\Projects\Java\Main.java`.

Then you can run your program this way too `java C:\Projects\Java\Main`

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678116/how-to-compile-a-java-project-with-a-terminal-cmd/36678408#comment60946469_36678116)... You can find a more detailed explanation to [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html).

Comment: This gives `javac: file not found: C:ProjectsJavaMain.java`

Comment: You need to provide `javac` the exact location of your java file. In my example, the Main.java file is located on a directory inside C:\Projects\Java\

Comment: What I wanted to say with my comment - It is better to use forward slashes, they work on both Windows and UNIX. The OP didn't say he used Windows.

Comment: @Ingo you're right. It's better to use forward slashes. I was assuming that he's using Windows. I was reading through comments and the op agreed to it about setting environment variables. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install java JDK which you can find [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Then you need to right-click on my computer->properties->advanced system settings->Environment variables -> Click on path -> New

Then add the path to the bin folder inside the install folder for JDK.

Then in cmd you can compile with

```
javac *.java
```

inside the directory of your code

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [**JDK**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

   (*Make sure your [**PATH**](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) variable is set up*)
2. Use SublimeText's [**Build System**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564613/how-to-compile-java-on-sublime-text-2-using-mac-os-x), which allows you to compile open `java` documents with the <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> command.

Answer (score 0):

You did not install JDK. You need to install JDK which has javac command.

[Installing JDK on MAC instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

[Installing JDK on Windows instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html)

After installing JDK(Java Development Kit), you can run the command `javac -version` on command line and let it show the version that is installed.

Comment: could you be more precise? like a link at least?

Comment: There were two links that inform you how to install Java Development Kit for MAC and Windows.