# Can javac process/include `.properties` files so that they appear in the output?

Tags: java, javac, properties-file

Currently I'm building a small personal project in Java which is a simple file server. I've implemented basic internationalization with usage of `ResourceBundle`. I'm using `.properties` files to store messages in different languages.

Till now I was using Vscode built-in java compilation process which was copying `.properties` files into its corresponding directory in the output. However now I'd like to write a build script for that project.

My command looks like this:
`javac -d ./bin -cp ./src ./src/**/*.java`.

This command however doesn't take `.properties` files into account. I searched web whether `javac` has ability to somehow process/include this files into output but found no answer. I know I can use Maven or Ant, but I'd like to make this project without usage of additional tools.

Comment: You're wasting time not using a build tool.  Resource files (such as .properties files) are handled easily with something like Maven.

Comment: I'll surely be using build tools soon and probably in every next project I'll create. I just want to test and sum up my current Java Core knowledge building this project using only indispensable tools. I think that understanding how things work is always profitable.

Comment: Then you'll need to manually copy the `.properties` files to what appears to be your `./bin` directory.  It's unclear if these need to be in packages but, if so, they need to be copied to the appropriate subdirectory under `./bin`.  Build tools are indispensable to professionals.

Comment: The adoption by build tools of the use of a "resources" directory was a poor decision, in my opinion. It would have been been quite natural and less contrived for them to treat any non-Java file under the "java" directory as class resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to my own question, but maybe someone will find this useful one day. In short `javac` always compiles `.java` files producing `.class` files. There is no way that it could process some other file (source:
[How to set the output files when compiling with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682472/how-to-set-the-output-files-when-compiling-with-javac)).

Long story short if you want to include resources, images, text files, anything that is not `.java` file in your output, and don't want to use build tools, you have to copy it manually or use `cp` command in your build script.

Answer (score -1):

This is why java .[jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jarGuide.html) files were invented.  You want to [create a .jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) and include your properties file, like so:

`jar cvfm myjarname.jar MANIFEST.MF src/*.class my.properties`