# Complication problem involving the method being undefined for the type

Tags: java, algorithm

I am currently writing this piece of program where you'd guess the number randomly generated by the computer. But the result I constantly got while trying to run this in VS code is: the method `extracted(input)` is undefined for the type `RandomNumber`. I have searched and noticed similar problems on google and other platforms but I can not seem to understand a word they are saying. So if anyone would be so nice and explain to me what the problem is would be very much appreciated. I am also wondering if this could a software error thing because a friend of mine was able to run this code in Eclipse perfectly while I cannot in VS code.

the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomNumber
{
    public static void main(String [] args )
    {
        int i = (int)( Math.random() * 101);
        int NumberToGuess = i;
        int NumberGuessed;
        int NumberOfTries;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int GuessedNumber;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false)
        {
            System.out.print( "Take a Guess Between Number 1 ~ 100! ");
            GuessedNumber = extracted(input);
            NumberOfTries++;

            if ( NumberGuessed < NumberToGuess );
            {
                System.out.print( "Your Guessed Number is Too Low!" );
            }
            if ( NumberGuessed > NumberToGuess )
            {
                System.out.print( " Your Guessed Number is Too High!");
            }
            else if ( GuessedNumber == NumberToGuess )
            {
                win  = true;
            }

        }

        System.out.print( "Your Guessed Number is Correct! You Win!");
        System.out.print( "The Number To Guess Was:" + NumberToGuess );
        System.out.print( "The Total Number Of Tries You Took is:" + NumberOfTries );
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have `extracted();` method that takes `Scanner` as argument? i believe you need to replace `extracted(input);` to `input.nextInt();`

Comment: `GuessedNumber = extracted(input);` You have never defined the `extracted` method. You must first write the method `static int extracted(Scanner input) { return in.nextInt(); }` or something similar depending on the logic.  Or you can just replace the `extracted(input)` with `input.nextInt()`

Comment: *I have searched and noticed similar problems on google and other platforms but I can not seem to understand a word they are saying.* Then why do you expect you'll understand a word we're saying? At least explain what you didn't understand so we can try to clarify.

Comment: Don't forget the unfortunate typo here `if ( NumberGuessed < NumberToGuess );` (remove the semicolon on the end of that line) - and use `else if ( NumberGuessed > NumberToGuess )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's edit your code, to make it right:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = (int)( Math.random() * 101);
    int NumberToGuess = i;
    System.out.println("rand is " + NumberToGuess);
    int NumberOfTries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int GuessedNumber;
    boolean win = false;

    while (win == false)
    {
        System.out.print( "Take a Guess Between Number 1 ~ 100! ");
        GuessedNumber = input.nextInt();
        NumberOfTries++;

        if ( GuessedNumber < NumberToGuess )
        {
            System.out.print( "Your Guessed Number is Too Low!" );
        }
        else if ( GuessedNumber > NumberToGuess )
        {
            System.out.print( " Your Guessed Number is Too High!");
        }
        else 
        {
            win  = true;
        }

    }

    System.out.print( "Your Guessed Number is Correct! You Win!");
    System.out.print( "The Number To Guess Was:" + NumberToGuess );
    System.out.print( "The Total Number Of Tries You Took is:" + NumberOfTries );

}
```

First of all, delete param `NumberGuessed`, it is odd.

Then, we need to read user guess int number: `GuessedNumber = input.nextInt();`.

Afterthat, we need to initialize to 0 our try counter: `int NumberOfTries = 0;`

And, the last part, we need to correct `if`, `else if`, and `else` statements:

```
if ( GuessedNumber < NumberToGuess )
{
    System.out.print( "Your Guessed Number is Too Low!" );
}
else if ( GuessedNumber > NumberToGuess )
{
    System.out.print( " Your Guessed Number is Too High!");
}
else 
{
    win  = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But even after I have changed accordingly to your advice there's still a problem occurring saying that the 'input' in line 10 is never closed. Despite this issue, the original problem is solved, although when I tried to run it and enter input values through my keyboard it just reads: Unrecognized request: { _request: evaluate }

Comment: about `is never closed`, you opened the resource of `Scanner`, after you finish the work, after all `System.out` statements, just put `input.close()` to close the connection. About unrecognized request, I run it, and played a game. You just need to enter in values, between 1 and 100, without any special symbols.

Comment: oh, it's just something about the default debug counsel in VS code which does not support keyboard inputs...but that's another story and another painful thing that I'll have to work on.

Comment: you could compile it using console and `javac`, after that run it using console and `java` commands. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678116/how-to-compile-a-java-project-with-a-terminal-cmd

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking a method: `extracted()` and passing in `input` and using the result of that to set `GuessedNumber`. Which is fine, except what does `extracted` do? I don't know, and neither does the compiler. If you have borrowed this code from an example, check and see if they implement a method called such and add the method to your class as well.

Another potential issue I see is that `GuessedNumber` and `NumberGuessed` are being used interchangeably, which is almost certainly not what you want to happen.

Comment: it is not exactly answer, because there are other issues

Comment: @BSeitkazin it is an answer as to what that error means. I just edited to address another issue I saw.

Answer (score 0):

**Please** follow Java variable naming conventions. Variable names should begin with a lower case letter. Next, prefer `while (!condition)` to `while (condition == false)`, and [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) to `Math.random()` (for example, your current generator could produce `0`). We can eliminate the raw `else` entirely by testing whether the current `guess` is equal in an assignment to `win`. And your formatting (on output) was *odd*. Putting that all together, your code might look like

```
int numberToGuess = 1 + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100);
int numberOfTries = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean win = false;

while (!win) {
    System.out.print("Take a Guess Between Number 1 ~ 100! ");
    int guess = input.nextInt();
    numberOfTries++;
    win = (guess == numberToGuess);
    if (guess < numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println("Your Guess is Too Low!");
    } else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println("Your Guess is Too High!");
    }
}

System.out.println("Correct! You Win!");
System.out.printf("The Number To Guess Was: %d%n", numberToGuess);
System.out.printf("The Total Number Of Tries You Took is: %d%n", numberOfTries);
```